# NodeJS video streaming to iOS doesn't work, but works on desktop Chrome and OSX safari

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I am trying to make this video possible to play in Safari on iOS: https://ekgcamp.com/api/videos/video1.mp4

The video works for desktop Chrome and OSX safari, but I have been struggling for days to make it play on iOS safari. Also, I am unsure how to debug it. The API supports range requests, and the video CODEC is AAC, H.264.

The API endpoint looks as follows:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import fs from "fs";

const handler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { videoName } = req.query;
  const filePath = `files/videos/${videoName}`;
  const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
  const fileSize = stat.size;
  const range = req.headers.range;
  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize - 1;
    const chunksize = end - start + 1;
    const file = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { start, end });
    const head = {
      "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      "Content-Length": chunksize,
      "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    };
    res.writeHead(206, head);
    file.pipe(res);
  } else {
    const head = {
      "Content-Length": fileSize,
      "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    };
    res.writeHead(200, head);
    fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
  }
};

export default handler;
```

The following headers are sent to and from Chrome and iOS safari

Chrome:

```
From: bytes=0-
To: {
  'Content-Range': 'bytes 0-397376/397377',
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Content-Length': 397377,
  'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
}

bytes=163840-
{
  'Content-Range': 'bytes 163840-397376/397377',
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Content-Length': 233537,
  'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
}
```

iOS:

```
bytes=0-1
{
  'Content-Range': 'bytes 0-1/397377',
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Content-Length': 2,
  'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
}

bytes=0-397376
{
  'Content-Range': 'bytes 0-397376/397377',
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Content-Length': 397377,
  'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
}
```

How do I make it work on both desktop and iOS? Cheers.

Comment: Have you done any debugging on the server to see EXACTLY what headers the IOS client is sending you and compared those to the other headers?  It seems likely that something is different and you aren't handling that correctly.

Comment: Also, you have a possible security vulnerability because you are building a path from `req.query`, but not filtering out characters that can allow an attacker to peer at other files on your server besides the ones you want to make public.

Comment: You also don't have any error handling if `req.query` specifies a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. Sanitisation and filepath checking has been implemented. However, I am still not sure where it's wrong. The headers sent from iOS are range headers expecting e.g. bytes 0-1234. However, from my perspective this seems handled correctly. I have provided an example above.

Comment: I'd suggest reading this article: [Streaming video in Safari](https://blog.logrocket.com/streaming-video-in-safari/).  If I had to guess, there is some technical detail that Safari is looking for that you aren't quite supporting properly.  It could be a HEAD request.  It could be the parsing of the byte range.  Details in the article.

Comment: Did the article I referenced in my previous comment help you out?  That seems to have the formula for making streaming work in Safari.